# How to render a video based on "material preview" viewport shading

Tags: rendering

I am trying to make a technical animation and i want to render a video based on the "material preview" shader type which looks like this:
[image]

I do not want a rendered view for my video, I tried adding a sun lamp and it looks really bad:
[image]

Is there a way to render a video based on material preview(top example) instead of rendered view? Thanks!

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/viewport_render.html

You can render your material preview viewport by following this guide.

Comment: Use Workbench render engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can render animation from viewport, by choosing *View* -> *Viewport Render Animation*

[[image: 1]

You may want to disable overlays (icon is located in top right by default), or disable specific parts of it in the drop-down menu. [image]